# Rails 4, specify custom foreign key in has_many through join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, associations, has-many-through

I would like to specify a custom foreign key in the join table for a has_many through association in my rails 4 app. Please see below, what I have so far...

When I execute `user.team_memberships.create` in the rails console, I receive this error:

`ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'user_id' for TeamMembership.`

users.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :team_memberships
    has_many :teams, through: :team_memberships
```

teams.rb

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :team_memberships
    has_many :members, through: :team_memberships
```

team_membership.rb

```
    class TeamMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :member, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'member_id'
      belongs_to :team
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "team_memberships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "member_id"
    t.integer  "team_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "team_memberships", ["member_id"], name: "index_team_memberships_on_member_id", using: :btree
  add_index "team_memberships", ["team_id"], name: "index_team_memberships_on_team_id", using: :btree

  create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "team_snap_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "teamsnap_uid"
    t.string   "teamsnap_access_token"
  end
```

Comment: what happened when you just added the foreign_key to the `has_many :through` relationship on both `User` and `Team` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add `foreign_key: 'member_id'` to the `has_many` declaration on `User`. You can also remove the `foreign_key` option on the `belongs_to` in `TeamMembership` - Rails will infer this automatically.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_memberships, foreign_key: 'member_id'
  has_many :teams, through: :team_memberships
```

team_membership.rb

```
class TeamMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :team
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify foreign key in both models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_memberships, foreign_key: 'member_id'
  has_many :teams, through: :team_memberships
end
```

and

```
class TeamMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'member_id'
  belongs_to :team
end
```

if you do not add foreign key in user model then you will not be able to create team membership for a user similarly if you will not specify foreign key in team membership then you will not able to get user of a team membership.